# Script to track who is liking or sharing through Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I was wondering if it's possible to find who is liking or sharing my web site or `<a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#">Facebook</a>` page by running a script. Obviously, you would have to use the Facebook API, but what I'm wondering is if it is able to do the following:

It is an incentive based share/like. I am trying to create a members section where they can share our website and receive a `<a class="inlineAdmedialink" href="#">credit</a>` in their member account. Also, if they physically click the "like" button on our page, a "credit" should be updated to their account. I would need to make it so that they cannot use multiple Facebook accounts to try to obtain multiple credits, but after they click the 'like' button in their account, the Facebook Like button should disappear, which I believe can be done through some PHP code (if).

The third "credit" they can receive would be if they 'share' our page on their own wall.

The way I see the process is that they do one of the above, and we have a cron script that runs every 5 minutes or so to check our database of e-‍mails/usernames to see if they liked/shared/or liked page, then it will be an easy process to add the 'credit' automatically.

Is this possible? If so, can someone please guide me to the part of FQL that I should read on? I haven't dealt with FQL yet, but I'm sure it shouldn't be too much of a battle for something like this.

Answer (score 1):

> It is an incentive based share/like.

[Facebook Platform Policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/), IV. Application Integration Points, 1.:

> *“You must not incentivize users to use (or gate content behind the use of) Facebook social channels, or imply that an incentive is directly tied to the use of our channels.”*

Just FYI …